# How to change or customize the colors from pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

hi I'm just starting to use pandas on python to graph some data instead of excel,
i want to customize the colors as well as the opacity of some given data because its always going into its default color lists

heres my code :

```
 from pandas import DataFrame
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

 x=np.array([[4,8,5,7,6],[2,3,4,2,6],[4,7,4,7,8],[2,6,4,8,6],[2,4,3,3,2]])
df=DataFrame(x, columns=['a','b','c','d','e'], index=[2,4,6,8,10])
df.plot(kind='bar')

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call `df.plot.bar` directly and pass a dictionary of column name to color mappings to the `color` parameter.

```
from pandas import DataFrame
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x=np.array([[4,8,5,7,6],[2,3,4,2,6],[4,7,4,7,8],[2,6,4,8,6],[2,4,3,3,2]])
df=DataFrame(x, columns=['a','b','c','d','e'], index=[2,4,6,8,10])
df.plot.bar(color={'a':'gold','b':'silver','c':'green','d':'purple','e':'blue'})

plt.show()
```

[image]